Can I specify the dimensions of an image in Microsoft Word, depending on its location?
I use a Word document as a template. It contains an image as last element. Sometimes everything fits on 1 page, sometimes the text above the image is too much and a second page is needed. I want the image's height to be at least 20% of the page height and if it does not fit on page 1, I want its width to be 80% of the page width. Is this possible without VBA?
In other words: Imagine, there is first text on the page, followed by an image.

If the text takes e. g. only 10% of the height, there is enough space for the image in full width.
If there is 70% text, there is 30% left for the image. If not the full width can be used, it is okay, resize the image to 30% height.
If there is >80% text, move the image to the next page. Use the full width.

If there is no built-in possibility, is there a workaround, like e. g. putting the image in a table or anything else?

(It is always A4. So, if it does not work with above percentages, I could use fixed values in cm or pt.)

Hello, what are you trying to archieve exactly ?

Thanks @Maslie for asking. I edited my question for clarification.

well my first guess, will be to use an image editor like paint.net to resize the image
